# How do I connect ads to adcreatives in Facebook Ads API v2.3?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

In the past, when I requested an ad from the API, it returned a field called "creative_ids" which I could use to get the connection between an ad and its creatives.

In version 2.3, this field has been deprecated. What is the best way to find the connection between and ad and its creatives now?

Answer (score 1):

The field is now called: "creative", the value is an object with the id field.

Eg: /?fields=creative

```
{
"id": "< AD_GROUP_ID >",
  "creative": {
    "id": "<CREATIVE_ID>"
  }
}
```